# Laravel 5.0 - Blade Template Errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5

Just playing about with Laravel 5, and am having difficulties using the Blade templating syntax. It appears that all my special characters are being escaped. Have I something wrong with my setup?

Just to show my setup, I have added the following to `config/app.php`:

Aliases: `'Form' => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', 'Html' => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'`
Service Providers: `'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'`

Now here's my blade view:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')

    {{ Form::open() }}

    {{ Form::close() }}

@stop
```

And here is the output in the browser:

`<form method="POST" action="http://test.app:8000/categories/create" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="m4RdpqdbbqQ2F7iwfDkSDKTzEmaBGNvpJbj5LnqE"> </form>`

And here is the output from view-source:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>My Site</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header></header>

        <content>
    &lt;form method=&quot;POST&quot; action=&quot;http://test.app:8000/categories/create&quot; accept-charset=&quot;UTF-8&quot;&gt;&lt;input name=&quot;_token&quot; type=&quot;hidden&quot; value=&quot;m4RdpqdbbqQ2F7iwfDkSDKTzEmaBGNvpJbj5LnqE&quot;&gt;

    &lt;/form&gt;

</content>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In [Laravel 5](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/833d90073da404df4b5b94c182f931b5c239fa10), `{{ }}` will auto escape. What you need to use now is `{!! !!}`.

```
{!! Form::open() !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

More read about the change can be seen on https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/new-blade-tag-for-unescaped-data-thoughts (thanks to @user1960364).

Comment: Perfect, thanks... WTF!!! Why Taylor change that? Will accept answer as soon as able.

Comment: Worth reading: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/new-blade-tag-for-unescaped-data-thoughts

Comment: It was changed for security reasons.  It's better practice to escape.  Having it default to escape prevent lazy programmers from making a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If you **must** use the old (L4.2 or less) Blade syntax, add the following lines at the bottom of AppServiceProvider@register:

```
\Blade::setRawTags('{{', '}}');
\Blade::setContentTags('{{{', '}}}');
\Blade::setEscapedContentTags('{{{', '}}}');
```

This should not be done lightly, and may make your application more vulnerable to XSS exploits, so use it with caution.

Comment: I wouldn't say this "may make your application more vulnerable to XSS exploits".  The old syntax is no more vulnerable to XSS exploits than the new syntax.  As long as you remember what notation to use for escaping vulnerable variables, either the new or old syntax do the same thing.