# Laravel: Getting plain text while using Form class

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner of laravel. I have just installed "illuminate/html": "~5.0" with the help of link http://www.ekoim.com/blog/fix-class-form-html-not-found-laravel-5/

Now when I tried using of {{ Form::open() }} {{ Form::close() }} in view file. It is returning form in plain text format to browser.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://project.dev" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="qNbi3DD1YGQncOv3PRBWl1l6BxVViWZnleVAmniS"></form>
```

I am attaching screenshot here.

[image]

Is there anything I forgot to do in order to this code to work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.0 - Blade Template Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832749/laravel-5-0-blade-template-errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Laravel 4, in Laravel 5 the content between `{{ }}` is now escaped by default. To output unescaped content you need to use `{!! !!}`. So in your case:

```
 {!! Form::open() !!} {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Read more in the [Laravel Templates Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates).